# Add two classes to a div, the first class should always apply but the second class should applies conditionally

Tags: reactjs, sass

I want to add two classes to a div, the first class should always apply but the second class only applies when the condition is true else it is not applied. I tried the piece of code below but I don't seem to get the desired result. something could be wrong with my approach.

`<div className={[style.carousalItem, pics.indexOf(item) === this.state.current ? style.currentItem : ''].join(" ")}>`

Comment: The tertiary statement looks good. Please post the whole component, the problem is probably there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES6:

```
className={`${style.carousalItem} ${pics.indexOf(item) === this.state.current ? style.currentItem : ""}`}
```

or

```
className={`${style.carousalItem} ${pics.indexOf(item) === this.state.current && style.currentItem}`}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this in a functional component :

```
const handleClass = () => {
   if(yourCondition){
      return "class1"
   }
   // Otherwise return class2
   return "class2"
}
const cls = handleClass()
```

```
<div className={`${cls}`}> ... </div>
```

In a class component :

```
handleClass = () => {
   if(yourCondition){
      return "class1"
   }
   // Otherwise return class2
   return "class2"
}
const cls = handleClass()
```

```
<div className={`${cls}`}> ... </div>
```